# Online magazine signs contract for compensation, publishes piece, never pays - What to do?

Tags: contracts

I sold a piece to an online magazine and signed a contract for a small amount. They never paid, their site seems to be at a standstill, and no one has responded to my emails. My piece was the last piece published, in January. It seems nugatory, to say the least, that I am carping about it, but a deal’s a deal. What should I do?

Comment: Hi August. "Has this happened to anyone?" seems largely unrelated to your main question, and it also has signs of a poll question, so I deleted that. I also edited the title of your question to try to better summarize the remaining question. Feel free to [Edit] further if you disagree with my edit.

Comment: This seems like a legal issue rather then a writing issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to Legal.SE?

Comment: Not sure it's off topic here, but I do believe Legal.SE would be better equipped to answer.

Comment: Yeah, you provided a good or service to a commercial entity under contractual obligation, they failed to live up to their end of the bargain, the fact this is a text is moot point.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus That would be [law.se], not Legal.

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: I honestly feel this is part of "publishing". It is only a legal matter **IF** the OP decides to take the issue to a lawyer which he didn't say he wanted to do. There are other options in this situation that may benefit him more, like promoting the published piece while the website still exists.